# memory layout of C++ object

Tags: c++, object, memory-layout

As far as my understanding all the member functions will be created in separate memory when class definition and is common for all objects. And only the member variables are created individually for each object. But how member function is executed when called using object?

Where is the address for these member function will be stored?

```
class B{
    public:
    int a;
    void fun(){

    }
};

int main(){
    B b;
    std::cout<<sizeof(b)<<std::endl;
}
```

If I execute this program, I get the output as 4(which is for only member variable). But calling b.fun() calls its member function correctly. How it is calling without storing its address within the object? Where the member function address are stored?

Is there anything like class memory layout where these addresses will be stored?

Comment: Your Google food for today is "c++ symbol mangling".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I do not think mangling would give the most direct answer.

Comment: Lets say you create a non-member function `void fun(B *b) {}`, and do `fun(b);`. Now it doesn't surprise you that an unrelated function doesn't affect the size of `B`? Member functions work similarly, just the syntax to call them is different.

Comment: The details vary between implementations, but usually a non-virtual member function is called just like any other function (with a hidden `this` parameter).  Commonly the address of the function to be called is "stored" within the call instruction itself, as an immediate operand.  There does not need to be space for a function pointer elsewhere; in particular, it is not stored in the memory layout of the objects of that type.  If you want to know about internals, specify your compiler / architecture / OS / ABI / code model / etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Non-virtual member functions are extremely like regular non-member functions, with the only difference between them being a pointer to the class instance passed as a very first argument upon invocation.

This is done automatically by compiler, so (in pseudo-code) your call `b.fun()` can be compiled into

```
B::Fun(&b);
```

Where `B::Fun` can be seen as a usual function. The address of this function does not have to stored in actual object (all objects of this class will use the same function), and thus size of the class does not include it.

Comment: Unrelated side note: Exactly how `this` gets into the method is not well defined by the C++ Standard. What's described above is the most direct way to do it and the only way I've seen in the wild. But `this` could be a hidden last parameter or transported into the method by Elf magic. The thing is, you don't really care how `this` shows up in a method so long as it does.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there anything like class memory layout where these addresses will be stored?

There is for functions declared `virtual`, yes.  In this case, the addresses of said functions are stored in a table and looked up at runtime.  This in turn allows your code to dispatch to the correct function depending on the object's type when the function is called.

Non-virtual functions do not work this way.  They're stored in the same way as free (i.e. non-member) functions, with the function name prefixed by the name of the class.  No storage space within the object itself is required.

In both cases, a hidden `this` pointer is passed to the called function.  This is what 'connects' it to your object.